# microsoft authentication using firebase

Tags: firebase, vue.js, authentication, vuejs2, firebase-authentication

I am working on Microsoft authentication using firebase. its a web project in vuejs 2 tech. I have followed this [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/microsoft-oauth#web-version-8) step by step for firebase and code section also followed this [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app) for creating account in azure portal but getting this error:

```
error FirebaseError: Firebase: Error getting verification code from microsoft.com response: error=invalid_request&error_description=Proof%20Key%20for%20Code%20Exchange%20is%20required%20for%20cross-origin%20authorization%20code%20redemption.&state=AMbdmDnE2TjhyB-T1hIHqYTh73Za9GIrASM-9NFz4trUb4QSLmP6W_qIFNCSl2fmUyq0tTvTNeB3Yg1a3XmOHg93aDItLCJTEEf9B-6EdpPLzR-_mkV9bI3QLoTyT3JQl9Pldczh3BfRlTZQ2KwKfV8IxgpHoXxKJByVzaB-M1wxWO9ESh7Ap_2BvNYHrq2tSFQHbK9D70l7xzi292de6G4rbGUgKmtuTtND4B671A1sxhD2-1WTWaCXkLMv_R7q5JTiWmfqn12ZipA_RWnMBDkPRhglBVReg6jBCRWKv1PvWN2dVQOQfjIoTKRfUs8VK4KfMDR6rYAVst8UStsO79nPN27_32yBjoU9pdl3 (auth/invalid-credential).
at _errorWithCustomMessage (vendors~app~._node_modules_@firebase_auth_dist_esm2017_index-1679a2b2.js~8334e211.js:568:20)
at _performFetchWithErrorHandling (vendors~app~._node_modules_@firebase_auth_dist_esm2017_index-1679a2b2.js~8334e211.js:1085:23)
at async _performSignInRequest (vendors~app~._node_modules_@firebase_auth_dist_esm2017_index-1679a2b2.js~8334e211.js:1100:29)
at async _signInWithCredential (vendors~app~._node_modules_@firebase_auth_dist_esm2017_index-1679a2b2.js~8334e211.js:4706:22)
at async PopupOperation.onAuthEvent (vendors~app~._node_modules_@firebase_auth_dist_esm2017_index-1679a2b2.js~8334e211.js:7965:26)
```

please suggest what could be the possible fix for the above issue

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this problem by doing under written 2 steps

step 1 : I created SPA platform on azure portal but it should be web platform so just deleted the SPA and added web platform to fix this problem

To configure application settings based on the platform or device you're targeting, follow these steps:

- In the Azure portal, in App registrations, select your application.
- Under Manage, select Authentication.
- Under Platform configurations, select Add a platform.    Under
- Configure platforms, select the tile for your application type
  (platform) to configure its settings.
  [image]

step 2: we have to Application secret in fire base console which need to be copied correctly from azure portal
basic steps to create and add a client secret

- In the Azure portal, in App registrations, select your application.
- Select Certificates & secrets > Client secrets > New client secret.
- Add a description for your client secret.
- Select an expiration for the secret or specify a custom lifetime
- Select Add.
- Record the **secret's value** for use in your client application code. **This secret value is never displayed again after you leave this page.**
  [image]

please read the last step properly which says we have to copy key value if you left the page the value will be hidden like this with *** so in that case just delete this key and add new client key then copy the value (it **"Value"** field not "Secret ID" field)

[image]

now just add that key to your fire base console in application secret field
[image]

**Note: try to follow these documentations properly [Firebase documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app) and [microsoft azure documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/microsoft-oauth#web-version-8)**